# python: from x import isn't work in directory

Tags: python

my files are look like this

```
-root/
 -main.py
 -nyaizhel_includes/
  -includemain.py
  -commands/
   -astolfo.py
   -naruto.py
   ...
```

from main.py, i import includemain.py

```
from nyaizhel_includes import includemain
```

it works, includemain.py gets imported,

from includemain.py i import commands

```
from commands import astolfo
from commands import narutobanner
from commands import rgirl
...
```

**includemain.py gets included but astolfo isn't get included, why?**

console log

```
heroku[main.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-13T09:42:02.840988+00:00 app[main.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-13T09:42:02.841010+00:00 app[main.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 42, in <module>
2021-04-13T09:42:02.841140+00:00 app[main.1]:     from nyaizhel_includes import includemain
2021-04-13T09:42:02.841141+00:00 app[main.1]:   File "/app/nyaizhel_includes/includemain.py", line 1, in <module>
2021-04-13T09:42:02.841258+00:00 app[main.1]:     from commands import astolfo
2021-04-13T09:42:02.841262+00:00 app[main.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commands'
2021-04-13T09:42:02.950174+00:00 heroku[main.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-13T09:42:03.023470+00:00 heroku[main.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: add an __init__.py file in nyaizhel_includes. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It doesn't help if you say "it's like this" and show a `naruto.py` and then include a `narutobanner` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't list your `__init__.py` file in your example, so make sure you add those so these are recognized as standard packages (although it seems you may already have).

The source of your error is likely that you're trying to do a relative import but specifying an absolute import:

If you use `from .commands import astolfo` (notice the period to signify relative import), that should resolve your issue. It is recommended to use absolute imports as per the [PEP 8 Style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) however. In your case this would be `from nyaizhel_includes.commands import astolfo`, assuming `nyaizhel_includes` is your root package here.

See the [documentation on Python packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages) for more information.